# How would I be able to convert the date into an integer?

Tags: ios, date, nsstring, integer

I need to be able to convert the date of the day to an integer so that I can then save it as an integer to use in other areas in my code. I know that there are other ways to save a date in Xcode, but for this specific problem I need to use it as an integer. So my over all question is how would I be able to convert the date into an integer so that I can then use that integer in an NSString? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you have your data as an `NSDate` or an `NSString` or something else? Do you want to save the whole date as a timestamp or just part of the date such as the day of the month? What have you tried so far to get what you need?

Comment: It's also worth noting that you can convert directly from `NSDate` to `NSString` in various, various different formats.

Comment: Generally, you use NSDate's `timeIntervalSince1960`, which yields a double-precision floating point value of seconds since 1960, then multiply by whatever multiplier (either 1000 or 1000000) is needed to produce the value you want.  Finally cast to an `int64_t`.

Comment: if your date type NSDate, you can use: NSInteger timeIntervalSince1970 = [date timeIntervalSince1970];

Comment: @hot why would you do all of that? There are perfectly good instance methods available that do this all for you.

Comment: Oops - yeah, it's 1970, not 1960.  Standard UNIX epoch, I believe.  (And I know of no instance method that will do the whole thing for you.)

Comment: @hot my example below demonstrates this :)

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger - Your example is not creating an integer.

Comment: @hot touché. I missed that requirement. For some reason I read it as a number. I tested converting it from double to int and back and lost no precision. I'm assuming Apple choose a double due to the potential size of the value.

Comment: The NSTimeInterval is a double-precision floating point number, expressed in seconds.  Most integer schemes are expressed in milliseconds or microseconds (though there is a Microsoft .NET format that is apparently seconds).  The internal clock in a computer is usually not rigidly defined as to precision, but is guaranteed to increment a low-order bit such that some time relationship is maintained.  Eg, the counter may be nominally in microseconds, but is really incremented every 256 microseconds at 8 bits in from the low-order end.

Comment: At most you would only ever loose 0.4 seconds when performing the conversion if you use the `round` function

Comment: Do note that if you just want an integer for the *day* (without including time), you can get the "Julian day" (in character decimal form) using an NSDateFormatter.  This is the number of days since January 1, 4713 BC.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` method.

```
// Get time from baseline date to now as a double.
double interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

// Re-apply the time value
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:interval];
```

Reference date is a base line date that will always have the same value. So you can safely use it as a reference point. Then you just store the `NSTimeInterval` (typedef to double) between the reference date and now. That gives you the number of seconds that has taken place between the reference date and now.

Edit:

As mentioned in the comments, if your date is eArlier than 2001, you can use the 1970 reference date.

```
// Get time from baseline date to now as a double.
double interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

// Re-apply the time value
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
```

If your dates are later than 2001, either method will work for you.

You may convert from double to integer using

int interval = (int)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

Since the double will be truncated to the nearest second, you will want to decide if you want to round up or down. Leaving as is will round down. You can round to the proper nearest second by using:

```
interval = round(interval);
```

Comment: Most schemes use 1960 as the reference date, so timeIntervalSince1960 is usually preferred.

Comment: You mean 1970? There isn't a reference point since 1960. I chose ReferencedDate as using 1970 generates a huge number that's not really needed for what he wants. Storing a reference point to 2001 is just as good with a smaller value.

Comment: the timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate is The interval between the receiver and the system’s absolute reference date (the first instant of 1 January 2001, GMT). If the receiver is earlier than the reference date, the value is negative. So better use timeIntervalSince1970

Comment: Yep, I mean 1970.  Misremembered.